# Protect SSRS Excel Export From Edit

Tags: xml, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am attempting to create a custom rendering extension in SSRS 2008 R2 (or 2012 if this functionality is made easier) to lock Excel exports of reports from editing by users; in other words, 'protected' exports.  My questions are, (1) How does one go about doing this? And also, (2) Is it possible to apply this on a report object level (item-level), or would this involve a change to RSReportServer.config that would apply to all reports on the server?

I realize that there are some third party apps, such as Aspose.Cells, that provide this capability, but given our infrastructure, it is unrealistic for us to have this implemented.  Is there a simple way of achieving this natively?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is a built in feature for this.  You would have better luck I think doing this in .NET with the office interop COM reference and then creating a read only copy.  A better question would be could a tiff or HTML not fit this need?  You may need to get some Excel junkies to think of using a different format. Or an HTML form consuming the service?  SSRS is pretty limited in things it can do for output.  However the availability of Front ends and intermediaries to talk to the SSRS Service is pretty vast.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you do not want to use a third party tool then this is not achievable with SSRS.

Assuming end users have some PDF Reader - granted a third party tool, but probably already in use - then is exporting the report in PDF format a suitable alternative?

Answer (score 0):

With SoftArtisans OfficeWriter's SSRS integration, you can create do this by turning on worksheet protection in the template Excel file that is embedded in the RDL when the report is designed with OfficeWriter's client-side designer (an Excel add-in).  The output file will be locked and protected.  See: [OfficeWriter for SQL Server Reporting Services](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-for-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx)

Disclaimer: I work for SoftArtisans, makers of OfficeWriter

Comment: OfficeWriter don't publish prices on their website, but they charge $1495 per CPU according to http://aspalliance.com/710_Review_SoftArtisans_OfficeWriter_v3.8